# How to use wordpress function wp_enqueue_script() in php?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a php function as shown below. The following function is being used at many places.

```
function render_brightcove_player($active_feed, $poster_image = false)
{
    $poster = '';
    if ($poster_image) {
        $poster = 'poster=' . esc_url($poster_image);
    }
    ?>
    <div class="hsc-video" onclick="hscLogo()">
        <div class="hsc-video__inner">
            <script src="//players.brightcove.net/1242843915001/SJ3Tc5kb_default/index.min.js"></script>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    wp_enqueue_script(                                      
    'miscellaneous-scripts',
    HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js"
    );
}
```

In the php code, I have added wordpress function `wp_enqueue_script()`. Inside miscellaneous.js file I am using:

```
function hscLogo() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("hsc-tv-logo")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

I am wondering if that is the right way to use `wp_enqueue_script()` function in php. Do I need to place **wp_enqueue_script()** somewhere else ?

This is the first time I am using `wp_enqueue_script` in wordpress. Here is the tree structure of javascript folders/files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is your php code in wordpress?
And if it is called by any wordpress template or plugin, you can use wp_enqueue_script in your php file.
You can check the following link to study wp_enqueue_script.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

```
wp_enqueue_script(                                      
    'miscellaneous-scripts',
    HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js",
    array(),
    '1.0.0', //Version
    true // Load in footer.
);
```

Comment: Is your php code in wordpress ? Yes, its a wordpress website. The above php code is inside a .php file. I am wondering why did you use `array(), '1.0.0', true`  ?

Comment: Also, can I use this `wp_enqueue_script(                                      
    'miscellaneous-scripts',
    HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js",
    array(),
    '1.0.0', //Version
    true // Load in footer.
);` inside a php function (I have used inside php function **render_brightcove_player**) ?

Comment: Third parameter is dependency, For example, if you are using jQuery in your js file, you can use array('jquery'), it means your js file will be loaded after jquery.js is loaded. Fourth parameter is version. Last parameter means whether you want to load this js in footer or not. In this way, you can use your js file after html dom elements has been loaded.

Comment: Yes, you can use this function in php function. For example, you can use it in your shortcode render function. Then your js file will be loaded where your shortcode is rendered.

Comment: I figured out something. The `display:none` style code was still in effect even if I delete all the code from file `miscellaneous.js `
I did that just for test. I am wondering what can be the reason behind it. Is it a wordpress thing or something else ?

Comment: Did you check developer tool on browser?

Comment: Yes, i checked the developer tools. The other thing which I noticed is when I comment this part of the code `wp_enqueue_script(                                      
    'miscellaneous-scripts',
    HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js",
    array(),
    '1.0.0', //Version
    true // Load in footer.
);`, then it stopped working rather than commenting the code inside `miscellaneous.js` file.

Comment: To repeat, display:none style code was still in effect even I commented all the code inside `miscellaneous.js` file. On doing CTRL+P, I can see
`miscellaneous.js` file with no commented code.

Comment: On commenting this section `wp_enqueue_script( 'miscellaneous-scripts', HSC_TEMPLATE_URL . "/assets/js/miscellaneous.js", array(), '1.0.0', //Version true // Load in footer. );`, 
`display:none` style code doesn't come in effect. Also, I can't see `miscellaneous.js` file on CTRL+P.

Comment: Do you still have a problem?